# How to match string using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a value that is : BG330 and i have one var search term which has value 330. Now i want to get this value which contains 330 and make this text bold.
How to match this sentence and replace with bold value??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy way:

HTML:

`<body>`
    `BG330 blah blah 330 blah blah 123304567890 ABCDEFG330HIJ <i>hello330</i>`
`</body>`

Javascript:

`var val = document.body.innerHTML;`

`MakeSearchedStringBold("330");`

`function MakeSearchedStringBold(s) {`
    `var r = new RegExp(s, "g");`
    `document.body.innerHTML = val.replace(r, "<b>" + s + "</b>");`
`}`

Try it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ogzqr4og/

Please note that this solution might replace existing HTML elements if they match the search string.

Answer (score 0):

var res = str.match(/330/g);
if match the condition then 
idofobject.style.fontWeight = 'bold';